# Create multi-line record into singe line when records are not demarcated

Tags: awk

I need to process records which are spread into multiple lines. For example, I need to convert multi-line record into the single line and then get whatever I need out of it. The records are not well demarcated, hence I cannot just set `RS` to `\n\n`.

```
cat input
constant_string bla bla1
bla bla bal
fooo foooooo baaar          #End of record 1
constant_string bla1 bla2
abcd cdfe fghi jkhil
foo bar bar bar bar bar bar #End of record 2
constant_string bla bla3
random data is present      #End of record 3
```

To achieve this, I have converted these un-demarcated records into demarcated on by adding new line between the two records like:

```
awk '{gsub(/^constant_string/,"\n&")}1' input

constant_string bla bla1
bla bla bal
fooo foooooo baaar

constant_string bla1 bla2
abcd cdfe fghi jkhil
foo bar bar bar bar bar bar

constant_string bla bla3
random data is present
```

Once I get the demarcated records, I can set `RS` to `\n\n` and do whatever I need.

```
awk '{gsub(/^constant_string/,"\n&")}1' input |awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'
constant_string bla bla1 bla bla bal fooo foooooo baaar
constant_string bla1 bla2 abcd cdfe fghi jkhil foo bar bar bar bar bar bar
constant_string bla bla3 random data is present
```

**Question:**

I am able to achieve the solution using TWO steps, is it possible to do it one step in awk ?

I tried following but didn't work:

```
awk  -v RS="" '{gsub(/^constant_string/,"\n&")}1'  input
awk  -v RS="" '{$0=gensub(/^constant_string/,"\n&",$0)}1'  input
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it will lead to extra parsing within the script. I like the streamed version a lot better, perhaps swap in sed for the first bit, e.g.: `<input sed 's/constant_string/\n&/' | awk '$1=$1' RS=`

Comment: _demarcate_ will be my word of the day. Had to look it up.

Comment: The reason what you tried didn't work is that by the time you're doing your sub() awk has **already** read the record using `RS=""` so you're just inserting newlines into 1 record which is the entire file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if you buffer to and process `b` at the next `constant_string` and `END`? Using `function`:

```
$ awk '
function process(str) { if(str!="") print str }
   /^constant_string/ { process(b); b=$0; next }
                      { b=b OFS $0 }
                  END { process(b) }
' file
constant_string bla bla1 bla bla bal fooo foooooo baaar
constant_string bla1 bla2 abcd cdfe fghi jkhil foo bar bar bar bar bar bar
constant_string bla bla3 random data is present
```

Comment: Use `if (str!="")`, not `if (str)` as the latter will fail when str evaluates numerically to zero. Use `print str`, not `print b`, or don't bother with an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="(^|\n)constant_string"}

   # filtering to avoid "empty" record
   /./ { 
      # $1 is first "word" (FS is default) AFTER your constant string that is
      # "removed" of $0 as Record separator.
      #  Info, this is now a multiline record

      #... treat what you want
      print " -- " NR : [" $0 "]"
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR "." i " : " $i

      }
   ' YourFile
```

Note:

- depend on awk version, posix seems to take RS string as any char inside the string as separator where gawk take the string itself (as regex in this case)
- check your constant_string to escape special chhar that are regex metacharacter

Comment: POSIX takes the **first** character of `RS` as the separator, not any character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have GNU awk -

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub(/\n/," "); print RS$0}' RS='constant_string' f
constant_string bla bla1 bla bla bal fooo foooooo baaar
constant_string bla1 bla2 abcd cdfe fghi jkhil foo bar bar bar bar bar bar
constant_string bla bla3 random data is present
```